# how to do append like python in scheme?

Tags: python, lisp, scheme, append, racket

Like this:

```
> (my-append (list 1 2) 3)
'(1 2 3)
```

I know `append` in `racket` is actually to concatenate two list.
And `cons` just add an element to the **head** of a list instead of **tail**

Does anyone have ideas about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Pyton, the `append()` method modifies the list in-place:

```
lst = [1, 2]
lst.append(3)

lst
=> [1, 2, 3]
```

Racket's lists are immutable by default, the closest thing to an in-place `append()` requires you to use mutable lists, and you have to pack the element to be appended in a list of its own:

```
(require scheme/mpair)

(define lst (mlist 1 2))
(mappend! lst (mlist 3))

lst
=> (mlist 1 2 3)
```

Notice that using immutable lists with the `append` procedure will produce a new list, leaving the original list untouched - so it wouldn't be "like Python":

```
(define lst (list 1 2))
(append lst (list 3))   ; this returns the new list '(1 2 3)

lst
=> (list 1 2)
```

In fact, Scheme's `append` procedure behaves just like Python's `+` operation between lists:

```
lst = [1, 2]
lst + [3]    # this returns the new list [1, 2, 3]

lst
=> [1, 2]
```

Come to think of it, Python's `append()` might have a misleading name - in most functional programming languages, the append operation is always defined between two *lists*, whereas in Python it's an operation between a list and an element. Maybe `add()` would have been a better name, like Java's `add()` operation of the `List` interface.

Answer (score 3):

If you're in Racket, you probably want to look into the growable vector library ([data/gvector](http://docs.racket-lang.org/data/gvector.html)).  This provides a container type that supports many of the features you're used to with Python's growable lists.

Example:

```
#lang racket
(require data/gvector)
(define lst (gvector 1 2))
(gvector-add! lst 3)
(for ([elt lst]) (printf "I see: ~s\n" elt))
```

Otherwise, your question ends up reducing to: how do I make immutable linked lists work like mutable sequentially-allocated arrays?  And that's not going to work well: data types are different for different reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean with "append like python", but if all you want is to insert a new element at the end of the list, you may use this:

```
(define (my-append lst el)
  (append lst (list el)))
```

Comment: Python's append method is a mutation on a vector-like data structure that supports automatic growing.  It's important to note that the term that Python uses, "list", should be defined as "growable, mutable vector".